# How to display the featured post on the category page?

Tags: plugins, posts, featured-post

I have created a feature post check box on the post page. Now what I am doing is if any user-selected that checkbox then I have to show that post on the category page. I tried below code but it's not displaying.

**Code is to add feature post on post**

```
// add feature post on post page
function register_post_assets(){
    add_meta_box('featured-post', __('Featured Post'), 'add_featured_meta_box', 'post', 'advanced', 'high');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'register_post_assets', 1);

function add_featured_meta_box($post){
    $featured = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_featured-post', true);
    echo "<label for='_featured-post'>".__('Feature this post?', 'foobar')."</label>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='_featured-post' id='featured-post' value='1' ".checked(1, $featured)." />";
}

function save_featured_meta($post_id){
    // Do validation here for post_type, nonces, autosave, etc...
    if (isset($_REQUEST['_featured-post']))
        update_post_meta(esc_attr($post_id, '_featured-post', esc_attr($_REQUEST['_featured-post']))); 
        // I like using _ before my custom fields, so they are only editable within my form rather than the normal custom fields UI
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_featured_meta');
// end feature post with check box tag here
```

Now I an displaying on the category page

```
 if(is_category()){
    //check if category is a subcategory
    $this_category = get_queried_object();
    if( 0 != $this_category->parent ){ //if subcategory then display feature post
//displaying feature post here
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'meta_key' => '_featured-post',
        'meta_value' => 1
    );

    $featured = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($featured->have_posts()): while($featured->have_posts()): $featured->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
    endwhile; else:

    endif;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in code to Displaying Feature post in category page. the problem is to add feature post meta into post.

First, `checked()` by default echo, so you have to pass `false` attribute to prevent echo.

```
function add_featured_meta_box($post){
    $featured = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_featured-post', true);
    echo "<label for='_featured-post'>".__('Feature this post?', 'foobar')."</label>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='_featured-post' id='featured-post' value='1' ".checked(1, $featured,false)." />";
}
```

second,  remove `esc_attr()` from `update_post_meta`, and you have to save empty value beacuse unchecked checkboxes are not set in the $_POST, so you'd have to empty their meta field.

```
function save_featured_meta($post_id){
    // Do validation here for post_type, nonces, autosave, etc...
       $featured_post = ( isset( $_POST['_featured-post'] ) ) ? $_POST['_featured-post'] : "";
       update_post_meta($post_id, '_featured-post', $featured_post); 
        // I like using _ before my custom fields, so they are only editable within my form rather than the normal custom fields UI
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_featured_meta');
```

Comment: Give me sometime to understand your answer

Comment: I tried your code but it's not displaying on my category page.

Comment: did you check data being saved in post meta table ? did you check into subcategory page ??? . i have checked code on my system and it is working fine.

Comment: I have a total number of 5 posts and I am getting https://prnt.sc/pwvhvy feature post on all the post and all are selected.

Comment: did you select category for that posts ? that category are subcategory ? did you view subcategory page where you add code to display feature post ?

Comment: The remaining post is displaying but only condition is not displaying

Comment: Wait a min. Checking again from my side.

Comment: okay. let me know.

Comment: There was some issue from my side. Now It's working.  Thanks for the help